# Error probability of a digital code through noisy channel

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose a binary message is transmitted through a noisy channel. The transmitted signal $S$ has uniform probability to be either $1$ or $−1$, the noise $N$ follows normal distribution $N(0,4)$ and the received signal is $R=S+N$  . Assume the receiver conclude the signal to be $1$ when $R>=0$ and $-1$ when $R<0$ .

What is the error probability if we send the same signal three times (with amplitude 1), and take majority for conclusion? For example, if three received signal was concluded $1, −1, 1$ by receiver, we determine the transmitted signal to be $1$.

I have knowledge about normal distribution but I have absolutely no clue of approaching this problem.

Comment: You have to calculate the probability of getting ($2$ wrong $1$ right) or (all $3$ wrong), where you are wrong when (noise $\geq 1$ when the signal is $-1$) or ($ < -1$ when the signal is $1$)

Comment: I am unable to understand that what does it mean by noise>=1 , as in the question its mentioned that the channel is noisy?

Comment: Yes, the channel is noisy and it is modelled by a normal distribution with mean $0$, variance $4$. So, you can calculate the probability of noise being greater than $1$, less than $-1$, etc. using the given normal distribution

Comment: Use the definition of cumulative probability distribution function to calculate probabilities, for eg. $P(X \leq -1 ) = F(-1)$